# How can I add a dataframe converted to an array as an element of another dataframe based on a key value

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've been trying to add the results of a dataframe as a new array field in another dataframe based on a key value.

For example, I have this data frame let's call it `df1`:

```
root      
|-- DF_KEY: integer (nullable = false)
|-- DF_DESC: string (nullable = false)

 +------------+--------------------+
 |DF_KEY      |     DF_DESC        |
 +------------+--------------------+
 |       10000|String Desc A       |
 |       10000|String Desc B       |
```

And another dataframe `df2`:

```
root
|-- DF_KEY: integer (nullable = false)
|-- COL_A: decimal(20,0) (nullable = true)
|-- COL_B: decimal(20,0) (nullable = true)
|-- COL_C: string (nullable = false)
```

I would like to combine the two dataframes with the results of `df1` as a new array `ARRAY_OF_DF_DESC` that would result in a dataframe (`newDF`) with the following schema.

```
root
|-- DF_KEY: integer (nullable = false)
|-- COL_A: decimal(20,0) (nullable = true)
|-- COL_B: decimal(20,0) (nullable = true)
|-- COL_C: string (nullable = false)
|-- ARRAY_OF_DF_DESC : array (nullable = false)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
```

I tried doing a join:

```
val otherRefsArray = df1.select($"DF_KEY", array(df1.columns.map(col): _*) as "ARRAY_OF_DF_DESC ")

val newDF = df2.join(otherRefsArray, "DF_KEY")
```

But this join only added a single `WrappedArray` for each `df1` row to the `newDf` dataframe.  And it returns duplicate records for each `DF_DESC`.

If possible, I would like to pass a `WrappedArray` containing all of the `DF_DESC` associated with the `DF_KEY` for that row.  Does anyone know how to do this with scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupBy()` and collect a list for each key.

```
val otherRefsArray = df1.groupBy($"DF_KEY")
  .agg(collect_list($"DF_DESC").as("ARRAY_OF_DF_DESC"))
```

Afterwards, use `join` in the same way as before.

Comment: Is that the only option?  i'm asking because I had some issues with groupBy because of some duplicates in the schema.  If there is no other option, I will address the duplicates and try the groupBy.

Comment: @RonniePhelps I would say `groupBy()` with `collect_list` is the simplest solution, I don't think you can avoid some kind of grouping on the `df1` dataframe as you have multiple identical keys. In this case, there shouldn't be any duplicate issues? Or are there other columns involved than this run the question?

Comment: This is just an example I posted for simplicity but there are other attributes that I didn't list that have duplicates in the schema.